# Deciding whether to use ws or wss?

Tags: tcp, websocket, udp

I have an account with a trading exchange and they have a websockets API which supports ws://... and wss://...

For the non-authenticated channels such as the current state of the orderbook, is it an easy decision to just use ws, mostly for the (however minimal) time savings? Obviously I would like to have my data as recent as possible.

I just want to check there's not some other factor which is more important than a few TLS encryption CPU cycles and ms in latency saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason not to use wss for all your connections, particular with a webSocket.  The normal webSocket use is to make a connection, then keep that connection for a long time and use it.  While there is a bit of overhead on every transmission because of the encryption, the main wss overhead is when you first make the connection and that only happens once per connection.

> I just want to check there's not some other factor which is more important than a few TLS encryption CPU cycles and ms in latency saved.

No, there is not some other factor.  In fact, the opposite.  There are more and more and more reasons these days to use TLS whenever possible to protect your privacy.

> For the non-authenticated channels such as the current state of the orderbook, is it an easy decision to just use ws, mostly for the (however minimal) time savings?

Why?  If wss is available, I'd be using it for everything.  If you actually run into a CPU problem down the road, you could revisit whether using wss has anything to do with it, but that is unlikely to happen and, in my opinion, you have nothing to lose by starting with wss.  While one wants to design code intelligently, you don't want to try to micro-optimize performance-related things before you even have a documented, measured performance issue to worry about.

General reasons to use TLS:

1. Privacy (nobody in the middle can snoop on what you're doing)
2. Security of data (nobody can read your data, not even proxies)
3. Security of endpoint (endpoint you're connecting to can't be hijacked without you knowing about it)

Comment: One reason would be that in a competitive trading environment, milliseconds matter. I am only talking about using non-encrypted ws for the public channel which is the current order book state. I may still end up using wss, but I just would like to make clear that security is an issue on the authenticated channels, not the unauthenticated ones.

Comment: @JSStuball - If ms matter, then you better go co-locate your server in the same data center with the source of the data.  That will likely matter orders of magnitude more than anything in your question.

Comment: I am colocated already. I don't want to get pipped at the post.

Comment: @JSStuball - So, what is your question really asking?  If anyone offers you some reasons why you should be using TLS (privacy, security), you just shoot them down using context that is not provided in the question.  So, I can't figure out what your question is really about?

Comment: I appreciate your replies but you brought co-location into the equation and I'm just saying its not relevant on this occasion. My question is really about the amount of time saved versus drawbacks of ws. Is your main point that if I don't use wss, the data I receive is potentially tampered with?

Comment: @JSStuball - Well, I added the general reasons to use TLS to my answer.  Not sure what else you want.

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to check there's not some other factor which is more important than a few TLS encryption CPU cycles and ms in latency saved.

Actually, there is.

This is also [stated in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.8):

> At the time of writing of this specification, it should be noted that connections on ports 80 and 443 have significantly different success rates, with connections on port 443 being significantly more likely to succeed, though this may change with time.

Some network intermediaries (especially with some mobile providers) will fail on `ws` connections but work properly when using `wss`.

The reason seems to be that these intermediaries (proxies / routers) will attempt to read the WebSocket message as if it were HTTP and "fix" HTTP errors or resolve caching (which actually corrupts WebSocket data).

The encrypted `wss` protocol will trigger a pass-through mode, since these intermediaries won't be able to read the data or "fix" any HTTP errors.

The Websocket protocol uses client-side frame masking for the same purpose, but sometimes with limited results. Using `wss` increases connectivity on some networks.